delete from the output of a select query using postgres
I have a query that will run and allow me to find out if i have persons in the DB with more than one active account number.   I was trying to setup this query to delete the additional accounts other than the one i specify i wanted to keep.   The query is below,   (the database layout is a lesson in relational db's and data is in multiple tables.
select c.id_value as Account_number, c.identifierdomain_key, d.id_value as Medical_Record_Number, a.admit_time, a.last_update_time, b.given_name as First_Name, b.family_name as Last_Name, l.nursing_unit as HIS_unit, l.bed as HIS_room_bed, l.encounterlocation_key, a.patient_key, a.encounter_key from encounter as a
inner join personname as b on a.patient_key = b.person_key
inner join encounteridentifier as c on a.encounter_key = c.encounter_key
inner join personidentifier as d on a.patient_key = d.person_key
inner join encounterlocation as l on a.assigned_location = l.encounterlocation_key
where a.patient_key in (select patient_key from encounter as a
group by a.patient_key
having count(a.patient_key) > 1 and d.id_value = '000000109')
order by last_name;

output of the query
when i add this code below i get an error at the if line,   i do have a secondary query that i can run that is the basis of the delete from lines where i pull the key values and that works.  Just trying to make something iterate though and remove but cannot seem to link the two queries together as one
**if c.id_value != '12342'**
    **delete from ccg.ccg.encounter cascade**
    **where account_key = a.encounter_key;**

    **delete from ccg.ccg.account cascade**
    **where account_key = a.encounter_key;**

    **delete from ccg.ccg.encounterlocation**
    **where encounttion cascadeerlocation_key = l.encounterlocation_key;**

    **delete from ccg.ccg.identifierdomain cascade**
    **where identifierdomain_key = c.identifierdomain_key;**
   ** end if**

sort of stuck trying to figure out how to take actions on the results of my select statement to automate this process where i have the datapoints just cannot link them together

If I'm understanding you correctly then this answer might help. If not please include your full attempt (your use of "if" seems to imply you are using a function but this is unclear)

What's the PK of table encounter? Postgres version? Actually, we'd need to see most of your relational design, to get the query right. What's ccg.ccg.encounter supposed to be? That's an illegal name for a table. if c.id_value != '12342' cannot work after select c.id_value as Account_number. You say you want to "delete the additional accounts" , but then you show deletes from 4 distinct tables. Why is and d.id_value = '000000109' in the subquery expression? I don't think you intend to do exactly what this does, but then it's not clear what exactly you are trying to do.

Thanks.. the ccg.ccg.dbname is the raw path,  i removed the ccg.ccg,  no difference,  still doesn't like something in the if condition.  I also tried adding a semi colon after the order by command to basically complete that task,  and still get an error in the if statement

getting the syntax error at or near "if"

"still doesn't like something in the if condition" as per the link in my previous comment if is not valid SQL (it's supported in PL/pgSQL but that is only applicable in function blocks).
